# @entangle initial state is always set to true on view side inside <x-jet-dialog-modal>

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I was wondering what could be the reason that `@entangle` value is always `true` on view side when the page is loaded. The behavior is normal when we change the value. The `divs` are inside the . If I extract them out `@entangle` normal from the initialization. To compensate for that i used `x-init="show = @this.dshow"`

```
Test.php


...
class Test extends Component
{
     public $dshow = false;
     ....
}

view.blade.php

<x-jet-dialog-modal>
    ...
   <x-slot name="content">
          <div style="max-height: 70vh">
                <div x-data="{ show : @entangle('dshow') }">
                     <label>
                         <input type="checkbox" value="1" wire:model="dshow" />
                         Check me
                     </label>
                     <div x-show="show">
                         This will be shown after you check abve
                     </div>
               </div>
          </div>
   </x-slot>
</x-jet-dialog-modal>
```

The above will not hide the div on load, but after we check and then uncheck the div is toggled as I wanted. I used `x-init` to force initial state. What could possibly be the reason? Is it a **bug**?